# Creating a 64bit build in Visual studio

Tags: .net, installation, 32bit-64bit

I have an old .net 2.0 windows app I need to deploy on a windows 7 machine and its not going too well. I want to build a native 64 bit version rather than a 32bit capable of running on a 64bit environment. I'm working with Visual studio 2005

My question is what settings do I need to set within each project of my solution, (both the windows app + my dll's that it references) and what settings i should set on my install project (I have a deployment project for distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not able to run 64 bit already?  By default projects created in Visual Studio are targetted at the 'Any Platform' and so on 64 bit systems run 64 bit.

If you do need to change it you can go to Build->Configuration and change the platform you want to target.

Brian Peek goes into it in more detail on his blog - http://www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2007/11/13/x64-development-with-net.aspx.

I'm not sure about the installer side but since they normally take the target built by Visual Studio I'm guessing you probably don't need to do much?